# Can't install Orc.Controls in a .Net Framework 4.7 project

Tags: catel

When I try to add the Orc.Controls package v4.2.8 from Nuget I get the error "You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework." The documentation page https://opensource.wildgums.com/ says that .NET 4.7 is supported. Am I doing something wrong, or does the pacakge just not support .NET 4.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to nuget, [4.1.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Orc.Controls/4.1.1) was the last version to support .Net Framework 4.7, you can install that version with: `Install-Package Orc.Controls -Version 4.1.1`

The [current version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Orc.Controls/4.2.8) is >= .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: This answer is correct. As (one of) the maintainer(s) of this package, I can confirm that only .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5 are supported going forward. This will decrease the load on our development team and we are only shipping apps targeting .NET 5 now ourselves so have no incentive to support full .NET FX.